# Arnol'd's definition of differential 1-form

Tags: differential-forms

In his *Ordinay Differential Equations*, Arnol'd mentions the following:

> Functions of the attached vector that are linear at each given point where thay are attached are called differential 1-forms.

Apparently, he's giving justification of going from the equation ${dx\over dt}=v(x)$ to ${dx\over v(x)} = dt$ and then integrating.

And this is pure confusion to me.

I've never before come across differential forms. So can you please explain in simpler terms?

**NOTE:** Please make sure that you're explaining it to a Physics undergraduate who is not very familiar yet with his new crush, mathematics.

---

I'm also attaching the screenshots for context.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: how much linear algebra are you familiar with? for instance do you know about  (abstract) vector spaces, dual space of a vector space, dual basis etc?

Comment: No, I’ve had only a first course in it.

Comment: could you be more specific about some of the topics involved? (just so I can try to pitch an answer appropriately)

Comment: @peek-a-boo I know about finite dimensional vector spaces, linear maps, eigenvalues, eigenvectors, operators, inner product, norm and orthonormality.

Comment: so is your confusion about the definition of one-forms? or is it something else? could you be specific about exactly what it is you're not understanding

Comment: Yep, I'm not able to understand them. Not even their definition. Can you break it down to motivate the concept?

Answer (score 1):

Before we even get to differential $1$-forms, you need to be comfortable with the standard differential calculus in higher dimensions. Very roughly speaking, the entire purpose of differential calculus is to study non-linear behaviour of functions by first approximating them by linear functions; this is literally the definition of the derivative. In single variable calculus, the derivative is often introduced as the "slope" of the curve at a point, but while this is geometrically nice, it is not the whole story. I hope you are familiar with the following definition for differentiability:

> Let $F: \Bbb{R}^n \to \Bbb{R}^m$ be a function, and fix a point $p \in \Bbb{R}^n$. We say $F$ is differentiable at $p$ if there is a linear transformation $T: \Bbb{R}^n \to \Bbb{R}^m$ such that
>   \begin{align}
> \lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{ \lVert F(p+h) - F(p) - T(h) \rVert}{\lVert h \rVert} = 0
> \end{align}
>   If such a $T$ exists, it is unique, and so we can unambiguously denote it by the symbol $dF_p$ (called the differential of $F$ at $p$).

Rewriting that equation, we get that $\Delta F_p(h) \equiv F(p+h) - F(p) = dF_p(h) + o(h)$, which in words says we can approximate changes in the function $F$ by a linear part, which is $dF_p(h)$, and an additional "remainder" term $o(h)$, which is "small" in the sense that $o(h) / \lVert h\rVert \to 0$ as $h \to 0$.

---

I'm not sure if this is an appropriate motivation for differential $1$-forms, but the way I like to look at it is as a geometric way of saying what $dF$ does. Suppose we deal with the special case $m=1$. Let $F: \Bbb{R}^n \to \Bbb{R}$ be a differentiable function. Then, for each point $p \in \Bbb{R}^n$, $dF_p$ is a linear transformation from $\Bbb{R}^n$ into $\Bbb{R}$. In symbols, we say that for every $p \in \Bbb{R}^n$,  $dF_p \in (\Bbb{R}^n)^*$ (this is common notation for the set of linear maps from $\Bbb{R}^n \to \Bbb{R}$). In other words, from the function $F$, we have constructed a new function $dF: \Bbb{R}^n \to (\Bbb{R}^n)^*$, which to each point $p$ assigns the differential at that point, $dF_p$.

Once again, the way you should think about $dF$ is that if you give me a point $p$, then $dF_p$ is a linear transformation which locally approximates the function near the point $p$. i.e if $h$ is a "displacement" vector with very small length, then if you are displaced slightly from the point $p$ to the point $p+h$, then the function changes by an amount $F(p+h) - F(p) \approx dF_p(h)$. So, $dF_p$ in a sense "measures and approximates" small changes to the function $F$ in a neighbourhood of the point $p$.

Now, a differential $1$-form is pretty much what $dF$ does. The following definition only works in $\Bbb{R}^n$ (I'm going to simplify some things by not going into tangent spaces of manifolds etc, and canonically identify tangent spaces of $\Bbb{R}^n$)

> **Definition:**
>   A differential $1$-form defined on $\Bbb{R}^n$ is a function $\omega : \Bbb{R}^n \to (\Bbb{R}^n)^*$

Notice how this is exactly the same thing as what $dF$ does. So a differential $1$-form $\omega$ is a function which for each point $p$, assigns a linear transformation $\omega_p: \Bbb{R}^n \to \Bbb{R}$. Just to emphasise again, $\omega$ can be thought of as a "function of two-variables" $\omega_{(\cdot)}(\cdot)$. In the lower slot, we input the point $p$ of interest. This leaves us with a function of $1$-variable $\omega_p(\cdot)$, which is linear. In this remaining slot, we can feed it vectors $h$, so that finally $\omega_p(h)$ is a real number.

---

By the way, I'm sure Arnol'd has an entire chapter later on related to differential forms, so perhaps it might be helpful to read up on that as well.